# Generate SharedAccessSignature for one time use

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to generate a **SharedAccessKey** which expires after the first request rather than after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You would need some mechanism of your own to track the usage of shared access signature.

Comment: The caveat here: You can't directly capture a GET using a SAS - that goes straight to blob storage. You can, however, use storage analytics to see that one (or more) calls have been made with the SAS in question (you can see the querystring when looking at the access logs). That would be the only way to know an SAS has been consumed. Otherwise, you'd need a different mechanism to access blob content (such as your own REST endpoint or WCF service).